# Converting a date type data to Firestore Timestamp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am starting in firebase/react and have been trying to convert data of type date to Timestamp to make a comparison. Still, I have found myself in the dilemma that it does not return me the nanoseconds only the seconds, so the comparison that I try to make fails.

**Output:**

```
Date from DateTimePicker:  Object { seconds: 1672488000, nanoseconds: 0 }
```

Document from Firebase/FireStore: Object { seconds: 1672488000, nanoseconds: 405000000 }

**Command line:**

```
let DTP_Date = Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(dateWithNoInitialValue));
console.log("Date from DateTimePicker: ", DTP_Date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Converts date in format yyyy-mm-dd to timestamp

```
const dateToTimestamp = (dateString: string):number => {
    const parts = dateString.split("-").map((i) => parseInt(i))
    // Date format yyyy-mm-dd
    const dateObject = new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2]); 
    return dateObject.valueOf()
}


console.log(dateToTimestamp("2022-01-12"))
```